# How should I configure connected app so I can choose another org during app authorization?

Tags: connected-apps

We have set up a connected app in our developer salesforce account to fetch campaign data in Slack. A node app has been configured to manage the app authorization and data fetching. On the app authorization page, I'm only able to login to a specific salesforce account to which I have previously logged-in and there's no way to choose another org.

In other OAuth connected systems like Slack, we'll have an option to choose the workspace (org), or sign-in to a new workspace that is missing with Salesforce Oauth or we don't know how to enable it.

Edit:
Even though the app redirects to common salesforce login, the response is hard-coded with a specific custom domain

[image]

Edit 2: The URL now goes to a generic login URL instead of a custom domain and also have the ability to choose a custom domain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `log out` of all the orgs you are logged in to see the flow in action with cookies coming your way!

The OAuth page in Salesforce will ideally land you on to the login.salesforce.com page for login and test.salesforce.com for a sandbox!

You can provide your username and password to allow `log in` to Salesforce and authorize!

Comment: Sorry, it is not. Even though our app redirects to login.salesforce.com, salesforce returns a custom-domain specific URL. I have updated my question to include the screenshot

Comment: What is hardcoded in your connected app? Also can you close the inspect console and put the screenshot!

Comment: Added the new screenshot as suggested. In the first screenshot, the login page is locked to our specific custom domain and there's no way to change it to another domain. I took a new screenshot now, it is showing generic login and also have the ability to choose a custom domain. Let me check with my colleague whether he changed anything. Thanks for the follow-up

Comment: It's because of your browser cookies! Once cookies have expired you are good to go!

Comment: Also note you can always change the top url to login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com and eveything should work

Comment: Thanks but I don't think we can update the URLs. The URLs also contain authorization code, redirect URLs. Also, changing the URL manually in OAuth looks more hackish. I believe we are missing something basic.